# Starting a thread in a Windows CE 6.0 service

Tags: multithreading, windows-services, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

I am developing a Windows Service under Windows CE 6.0. The project produces a DLL, which gets integrated in OS Image. The service gets started, when the WinCE boots thanks to registry settings.

The problem is that I am not able to start the "Thread1" thread. I should see the MessageBox, but there is nothing on the screen. Why? Putting the MessageBox into SFC_Init works fine.

Another thing - when I type "services list" in the console (in the WinCE system), the state of my service is unknown... Why is that so?

Please help!

```
// SrvForCom.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
//


#include "stdafx.h"

HINSTANCE hInst;

// main entry point of the DLL
BOOL WINAPI DllMain( HANDLE hModule, 
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, 
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    hInst = (HINSTANCE)hModule;

    switch(ul_reason_for_call) {

        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            DisableThreadLibraryCalls((HMODULE)hModule);
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;

    }

    return TRUE;
}

// function called during initialization process
DWORD SFC_Init(DWORD dwContext) {

    PSRVCONTEXT pSrv;
    HANDLE hThrd;
    DWORD err = ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;


    // fill the info structure
    pSrv->servState = SERVICE_STATE_UNKNOWN;
    switch (dwContext) {
        case SERVICE_INIT_STARTED:
            pSrv->servState = SERVICE_STATE_ON;
            break;

        case SERVICE_INIT_STOPPED:
            pSrv->servState = SERVICE_STATE_OFF;
            break;
    }


    // start new thread
    hThrd = CreateThread (NULL, 0, Thread1, NULL, 0, NULL);
    if (hThrd) {
        CloseHandle (hThrd);
        err = 0;
    } else {
        err = GetLastError();
    }

    return hThrd;
}

BOOL SFC_Deinit(DWORD dwData) {
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL SFC_Open(DWORD dwData, DWORD dwAccess, DWORD dwShareMode) {

    PSRVCONTEXT pSrv = (PSRVCONTEXT)dwData;

    return (DWORD)pSrv;
}

BOOL SFC_Close(DWORD dwData)  {
    return 1;
}

BOOL SFC_IOControl(DWORD dwData, DWORD dwCode, PBYTE pBufIn,
              DWORD dwLenIn, PBYTE pBufOut, DWORD dwLenOut,
              PDWORD pdwActualOut) {

    PSRVCONTEXT pSrv = (PSRVCONTEXT)dwData;

    switch (dwCode) {
        case IOCTL_SERVICE_STATUS:
            *pBufOut = pSrv->servState;
            break;
    }

    return 1;
}

DWORD WINAPI Thread1(LPVOID lpv) {


    MessageBox (NULL, TEXT ("The thread has been successfully started!"), TEXT ("Info"), MB_OK);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer to this question. The code above is correct apart from one detail - uninitialized structure. "pSrv" is a pointer (type PSRVCONTEXT) to a struct SRVCONTEXT with "servState" field. When executing "pSrv->servState = SERVICE_STATE_UNKNOWN;" some part of the memmory was overwritten, causing errors in the application.

The solution is to first allocate the memmory to this structure before using it:

```
pSrv = (PSRVCONTEXT)LocalAlloc (LPTR, sizeof (SRVCONTEXT));
```

After adding above line to my application, everything started working fine. The thread properly started and the service's state changed to "Running".

P.S. The structure looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
    DWORD servState;
} SRVCONTEXT, *PSRVCONTEXT;
```